# Blurry font in Atom editor[Debian]

Tags: debian

There is this blurry font problem with Atom editor on Debian.

[image]

I've tried everything, but did not succeed. Also look at the menu fonts. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the antialiasing mode from `rgba` to `grayscale` did the trick for me.

You will find this setting via `dconf` in:

`/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/antialiasing`

... or via `gnome-tweak-tool` under `Fonts` > `Antialiasing`.